# How to import or load Dumbbell chart in react app

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to use Dumbbell chart of highcharts in react app.
As per the link below, I have imported dumbbell module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official#how-to-add-a-module

```
import highchartsDumbbell from 'highcharts/modules/dumbbell';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

highchartsDumbbell(Highcharts);
```

And wrapping the options and data in HichartsReact component as below:

```
<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
```

Getting below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at dumbbell.js:16
at h (dumbbell.js:8)
at dumbbell.js:15
```

Could you please suggest if anything is missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the dumbbell series requires also the `highcharts-more` package.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.dumbbell

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xhxdyv?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It worked. I was importing depcrecated highcharts-more npm package!